# why isn't this login form code working?

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, pdo

I'm working on this since Thursday night but I can not figure it out what I'm doing wrong . I'm trying just create a simple login form . I have user and admin .when I'm trying to login as a user it says the user's username and password is invalid even my password and username are correct .any help appreciate it in advance .

```
<?php

include 'Fonctions/fonctions.php';
teteHtml("Login");
enTete($messageErreur);

//store the values found in SESSION
$username = "";
$password = "";
$loginError = "";
if (isset($_POST["login"])) {
    createCookie();
    echo $loginError;
} else {
    if (isset($_POST["deconnexion"])) {
        deleteCookie();
    }
}

function createCookie() {
    //if (isset($_POST["uname"], $_POST["psw"])) {
    if (isset($_POST["login"])) {
        //check if the system is lock
        if (isset($_SESSION["login_error"]) && $_SESSION["login_error"] >= 3) {
            die("Plusieurs essaies sont interdits!");
        } else {


            $connection = getDatabaseConnection();


            $salted = "wrntjkhn4wervfmm" . $_POST["password"] . "wo2i45djk";
            $hashed = hash('sha512', $salted);


            $stmt = $connection->prepare("CALL login(?,?)");
            $stmt->bindParam(1, $_POST["username"]);
            $stmt->bindParam(2, $hashed);
            //echo json_encode($stmt->errorInfo());
            // call the stored procedure
            $stmt->execute();


            if ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
                $_SESSION["username"] = $row["username"];
            } else if ($_POST["username"] == "admin" && $_POST["password"] == "admin") {
                $_SESSION["username"] = "admin";
            } else {
                if (isset($_SESSION["login_error"])) {
                    echo $_SESSION["login_error"] . "jjjj";
                    $_SESSION["login_error"] ++;
                } else {
                    $_SESSION["login_error"] = 1;
                }
                if ($_SESSION["login_error"] >= 3) {
                    echo "you put 3 times wrong password.";
                }
                //echo gettype($_SESSION["login_error"]). ($_SESSION["login_error"] >= 3);
                die("password and username are invalid");
            }
        }
    }
}

function deleteCookie() {
    //$_SESSION["uname"] = "";
    session_destroy();

    //refresh the page
    //header("Location: Mon_compte.php");
}

include 'html/login.html';

?>
```

```html
    <form  method="POST"  action="login.php">

      <label><b>Username</b></label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="username" required>

      <label><b>Password</b></label>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" required>

      <button type="submit" name="login">Login</button>
      <!--<input type="checkbox" checked="checked"> Remember me-->
      <span id="error_connection"></span>

      <span class="psw">Forgot <a href="#">password?</a></span>

  </form>
```

```
BEGIN
select username, password from users
    where username = p_username and password = p_password;
END
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary... You need to debug step by step with a var_dump() and a exit() then you will find the problem..

Comment: you haven't add any `form action` that's the main problem you are facing

Comment: `<form method="POST" action="YOUR_LOGIN_FILE_NAME.php">` you should have your form code similar to this.

Comment: @RakibulIslam i put this     <form  method="POST"  action="login.php"> bro but still does not work im getting same error

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**mySql Database/Table**

Database Name - `Login`

Table Name - `Users`

Table Columns -

> id(primary_key) | username | passcode

**DBConnection.php**

```
<!-- Fill in the data below with your appropriate data -->

<?php
   define('server', 'localhost:3036');
   define('username', 'root');
   define('password', 'root_password');
   define('database_name', 'login');
   $db = mysqli_connect(server, username, password, database_name);
?>
```

**Login.php**

```
<?php
   include("DBConnection.php");
   session_start();

   if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {         
      $myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['username']);
      $mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['password']); 
      $sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '$myusername' and passcode = '$mypassword'";
      $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
      $active = $row['active'];
      $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

      if($count == 1) {
         session_register("myusername");
         $_SESSION['login_user'] = $myusername;
         header("location: welcome.php");
      }else {
         $error = "Your Login Name or Password is invalid";
      }
   }
?>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Login Page</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div align = "center">
         <div>Login</div>   
         <form action = "" method = "post">
             <label>UserName  :</label><input type = "text" name = "username" class = "box"/><br /><br />
             <label>Password  :</label><input type = "password" name = "password" class = "box" /><br/><br />
             <input type = "submit" value = " Submit "/><br />
         </form>
         <div><?php echo $error; ?></div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

**Session.php**

```
<?php
   include('DBConnection.php');
   session_start();

   $user_check = $_SESSION['login_user'];

   $ses_sql = mysqli_query($db,"select username from users where username = '$user_check' ");

   $row = mysqli_fetch_array($ses_sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

   $login_session = $row['username'];

   if(!isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
      header("location:Login.php");
   }
?>
```

**Welcome.php**

```
<?php
   include('Session.php');
?>
<html>     
   <head>
      <title>Welcome </title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>Welcome <?php echo $login_session; ?></h1> 
      <h2><a href = "Logout.php">Sign Out</a></h2>
   </body>
</html>
```

**Logout.php**

```
<?php
   session_start(); 
   if(session_destroy()) {
      header("Location: Login.php");
   }
?>
```

Comment: I hate "answers" like this. Blob of code without any explanation. Downvoted

Comment: SO serves as kind of knowledge base for others as well. It's not just your problem being addressed here but also others may benefit from existing answers in future. Its also in your interest to ensure the answer will be useful and readable and understandable by others in  future, otherwise it's just useless from that perspective.

Comment: I will happily withdraw my downvote and upvote your post once you edit the answer to make it more educational. Comment here when this happens to ensure i do not miss that